# How to write output compiler in java?

Tags: java, quine

Is there a way to make a quine in java, then have some sort of program recognize the output as a program, then run that and give an output, and keep on doing so infinitely? I'm trying to write a self-replicating code and get it to infinitely reproduce itself, thereby technically creating life. I have a superiority complex, I suppose

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, your superiority complex has nothing to do with this. Show us the code you've written so far and where you need help.

Comment: haven't actually written code for this, just wondering how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an article that should assist you in your initial research:

[Meta-programming -Write programs that generate other programs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-metaprog1/index.html)

This wiki page can also point you to additional sources of information. 
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming)

Hope this helps you in your learning!